# Не удается добавить структуру в NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, структуры, xcode

Существует некоторая структура

```
struct Pokupki p1;
   p1.code = 1;
   p1.cost = 99.90;
   p1.name = @"Конфета";
```

При попытке добавить её в массив, упирается всеми своими структурными силами :)

```
NSMutableArray *PokupkiArr = [NSMutableArray array];
[PokupkiArr addObject: p1];
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Sending 'struct Pokupki' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'
```

Кстати, так обращаться верно?

```
NSLog(@"%d", PokupkiArr[0].code);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура - не объект, потому и не дает добавить.

Создайте класс:

```
//Pokupki.h
@interface Pokupki : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) float cost;
@end

//Pokupki.m
@implementation Pokupki

@end
```

В классе, в котором вы работаете с массивом:

```
Pokupki *pokupka = [Pokupki new];
pokupka.cost = 99.0;

NSMutableArray *all = [NSMutableArray new];
[all addObject:pokupka];

NSLog(@"%f", ((Pokupki *)all[0]).cost);
```

Comment: И никак это не обойти?

Comment: Создайте класс и добавляйте объекты

Answer (score 3):

Я юзал NSValue:

```
  struct Pokupki p1;
  p1.code = 1;
  p1.cost = 99.90;
  p1.name = @"Конфета";

  //Засовываем в массив
  NSValue *anObj = [NSValue value:&p1 withObjCType:@encode(p1)];
  NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anObj, nil];

  //Высовываем из массива
  NSValue *anObj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
  Pokupki struct;
  [anObj getValue:&struct];
```

Answer (score 0):

не используй структуры в `objective-с` - используй классы. Насколько мне известно, `ARC` не справляется со структурами

Comment: Что не так?

    @interface Pokupki : NSObject
    {
        float       cost;
    }
    
    @end
    


     p1.cost = 99.90;

Comment: `@interface Pokupki : NSObject`

`@property NSInteger code;`
`@property NSFloat cost;`
`@property NSString name`

`@end`

Comment: После

        Pokupki1 *p1;    
        p1.code = 1;  
        p1.cost = 99.90;  
        p1.name = @"Конфета";  
        [PokupkiArr addObject: p1];  


p1 = nil

Comment: `Pokupki1 *p1 = [[Pokupki1 alloc] init];`

Comment: через дебагер посмотри что не так выполняется, всё норм должно быть